# Error table expected when trying to add display object to scene group in composer

Tags: lua, coronasdk

i have a `diplay` object which is created outside the scene life cycle function and i want to add it to `sceneGroup`

```
 local trans
    local function tra( )
      trans = display.newImage('assets/gray.png',indicesToOuterCordinate(layout.finalx,layout.finaly,layout.finalside,false))
      physics.addBody( trans, "static")
      trans:addEventListener( "collision", lis )
    end
```

but when i try to add this i get an error table expected

```
sceneGroup:insert( trans )
```

even my function `tra` is called before i try to add the `trans` display object to `sceneGroup`

Comment: Your code is not giving us enough information to help you... We need to see where this function is placed and where you call sceneGroup:insert. I can tell you already that its 99.99% a misplacement of your code. So show us the scene:Create or where you do this logic.

Comment: i placed my function tra outside all of life cycle function

Comment: and sceneGroup:insert is inside the create function

Comment: Have to place it inside.

Comment: thx @Frozire it works without error but my problem is when i move a display object and place it on the top of other display object the old display object still appear on the top even that all my display object became on same scenegroup

Comment: sceneGroup:insert(1, imageForBack) and sceneGroup:insert(2, imageForFront) - should do the trick. The 1 and 2 define what "Layer" the display object is displayed at. You can put any number depending how "deep" you want it.

Comment: when added 1 and 2 for the layout the first added image with layout 1 is stack on the top

Comment: Then swap the numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to quickly gather the answer up in a single reply.

The initial problem/question was solved by moving the function and declaration, inside the `function scene:create( event )` for proper instantiation.

```
function scene:create( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view

    local trans

    local function tra()
      trans = display.newImage('assets/gray.png',indicesToOuterCordinate(layout.finalx,layout.finaly,layout.finalside,false))
      physics.addBody( trans, "static")
      trans:addEventListener( "collision", lis )
    end

    tra()
    sceneGroup:insert( trans )

    -- More code here

    end
```

Solving this problem triggered a new question in regards to layering the images in the application.

This was solved by adding the displayObjects to the display group together with an index value, indexing the position of the layer on the Z axis.

```
sceneGroup:insert(2, imageForBack) 
sceneGroup:insert(1, imageForFront)
```

Comment: i have another problem in collision detection i asked it in separate question but i wonder if i can detect collision on two object in different sceneGroup?and that my question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24983950/collision-detection-doesnt-work-inside-sceneshow  and thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Is there an other solution if you don't want the function inside the scene:create?