# collision detection doesn't work inside scene:show

Tags: lua, coronasdk, collision-detection

I'm trying to detect collision on two object inside my `scene:show` function

This is my first set of objects which have a collision listener on it

```
for i = 1, table.maxn(layout.playgrid) do
  physics.addBody( leftholes[i], "static" )
  sceneGroup:insert(3,leftholes[i])
  leftholes[i].name = "hole"
  leftholes[i]:addEventListener( "collision", lis )
  physics.addBody( rightholes[i], "static")
  sceneGroup:insert(3,rightholes[i])
  rightholes[i].name = "hole"
  rightholes[i]:addEventListener( "collision", lis )
  physics.addBody( topholes[i], "static" )
  sceneGroup:insert(3,topholes[i])
  topholes[i].name = "hole"
  topholes[i]:addEventListener( "collision", lis )
  physics.addBody(bottomholes[i], "static")
  sceneGroup:insert(3,bottomholes[i])
  bottomholes[i]:addEventListener( "collision", lis )
  bottomholes[i].name = "hole"
end
```

and this is the object which will collision with the hole object

```
hand = display.newImage("assets/hand.png",350,490)
hand.name = "hand"
physics.addBody( hand, "static")
```

and that my collision listener

```
local function lis(event)
if event.phase == "began" and event.object2.name=="hand" then  
print( "detected" ) 
local function tra( )
  trans = display.newImage('assets/gray.png',indicesToOuterCordinate(layout.finalx,layout.finaly,layout.finalside,false))
  physics.addBody( trans, "static")
  sceneGroup:insert(trans)
  hand:toFront()
end
end
end
```

Comment: Are you getting any error when running this code?

Comment: just the error when i use the trans object and of course that will happen because tans object still not instantiated  bot if i remove this block outside the listener no i don't get any error

Comment: Having a hard time understanding what the problem is then? The detection doesn't seem to trigger? Or does the code not run at all?

Comment: detection doesn't trigger

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether your are adding your collision listener with the RuntimeEvent listener .

If you does not add your collision with runtime event listeners your will not be detected .

```
local function onCollision( event )

if ( event.phase == "began" ) then

    print( "began: " .. event.object1.myName .. " and " .. event.object2.myName )

elseif ( event.phase == "ended" ) then

    print( "ended: " .. event.object1.myName .. " and " .. event.object2.myName )

end
end
```

Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", onCollision )